# Matlab GUI standalone application runtime error on 32-bit only

Tags: matlab, 32bit-64bit, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have a [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) GUI application that I generate a standalone executable application from it for both [**Windows 64-bit**] and [**Windows 32-bit**].

The *Windows 64-bit* version of the standalone application works fine without any problems, but the one on *Windows 32-bit* has some runtime errors, that some functionality of the application isn't working, and I can't debug to see where is the error exactly.

The GUI itself with being a standalone application is working fine in both Windows 32-bit and Windows 6-bit.

What Could be the problem here ?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on how it does not work? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: a button that do some functionality omit error sound and does nothing, and that happens only in the standalone application on Windows 32-bit

Comment: If it only occurs for 1 or a limited number of buttons I would look into the code that is called on clicking this specific button.
If you are having trouble isolating the piece of code that causes the problem try calling only 'half' of the code and see if it still occurs.

Comment: I'm working on so,I'm also trying to output messages after every line to decide which line throw this error !